# COUNTIF with Filter function in google sheet

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

In my google sheet, I have trade entries with dates. I am trying to prepare sheet which can provide the number of trades in each months depends upon the year selected. I am trying use filter function to filter the year first, and then month and then trade count. But current function always giving zero result. Is this approach correct ?

[Demo Excel sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1uTjBLXCK4Aqf_Vh0gww01HbRhlR5AcRI1RPwYDaVgQU/edit?usp=sharing)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you bind to your formula, you don't need to apply the filter function twice, because in this function you can apply multiple criteria to filter the data `FILTER(range, condition1, [condition2, ...])`.

In your case, you can apply the following formula `=COUNTIF(filter(YEAR(A2:A),MONTH(A2:A)=1,B2:B="Trade"),F2)`, where filtering by `month` and filtering by `"Trade"` takes place at once

You can also use one array formula `=ArrayFormula(countif(YEAR(A2:A)&MONTH(A2:A)&B2:B,F2&SEQUENCE(1,12,1,1)&"Trade"))` to perform this task, which will do the same thing as the 12 `countif()` formulas.
Here we form the data array `YEAR(A2:A)` & `MONTH(A2:A)` & `B2:B`, which will assemble the data into the following form

[image]

which we will check for consistency with `Year` & `Month` & `"Trade"` data, but only instead of one month you can substitute all 12 months using the formula `SEQUENCE(1,12,1,1,1)`

[image]